# How to use botkit to send a message at a certain time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack-api, botkit

After looking through the documentation of Botkit I don't see a way for a bot to initiate a message to a channel by itself at a certain time. What I've tried doing is providing a callback function to the .startRTM function that does what I want it to do at certain times, however the calls are asynchronous to retrieve information from another API. Is there a better way to approach this than sticking everything in a `while(1) {}` call? If not, how can I get the r.getHot callback to succeed because JS is running on the main thread so it'll skip over the callback function. The variable r is from the snoowrap library.

```
var bot = controller.spawn({
        token: process.env.slacktoken,
        incoming_webhook: {
            url:  process.env.webhookurl
        }
}).startRTM(function(err, bot, payload) {
    if (!err) {
        while(1){
            for (var i = 0; i < allowableTimes.length; i++) {
                if (new Date().getTime() == allowableTimes[i].getTime()) {
                    r.getHot('aww', {limit: 1}).then(function(res){
                        var url = res[0].url;
                        var title = res[0].title;
                        console.log(url);
                        console.log(title);
                        bot.sendWebhook({
                            username: "bawwt",
                            icon_emoji: ":smile_cat:",
                            text: "<" + url + "|" + title + ">",
                            channel: "#random"
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I misread your question at first

I'd suggest looking into [node-schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule). Be aware that if you're on a host that sleeps their processes, I don't think this will work. Otherwise, this is a better way than your while loop.

Leaving the below for others who find this

---

To originate a message without user input with Botkit:

Spawn a bot, `var bot = controller.spawn(opts)`, then call bot.say() anywhere bot is in scope.

```
bot.say(
  {
    text: 'my message text',
    channel: 'C0H338YH4' // a valid slack channel, FB
  }
);
```

For more info, check out [the docs](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit/blob/master/docs/readme.md#originating-messages)